# APi's for Tool Integrations to an existing toolchain

Tags: ibm-cloud, postman, devops-services

I tried to add a delivery pipeline and git repo to an existing toolchain using a POST request through POSTMAN.

BUT I just get "IBM cloud is under maintenance" ERROR

Is this functionality included in ibm(adding toolchain integrations to existing toolchain using API) or i am doing something wrong?

Was able to create a toolchain using post request.
Also there is no Documentation provided for it.

*Tried doing it using POST request*
**URL-https://cloud.ibm.com/devops/catalog/pipeline

Parameters as body- toolchainId=sample,env-id=ibm:yp:eu-gb,autocreate=true 
Authorization-bearer iam token**

[image: SEE IMAGE]

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: We need to automate Addition of delivery pipelines and git repos for n releases of Apps.

Comment: Doing it manually is very time consuming and hampers the productivity.

Comment: How often do you create a toolchain? You can create it (semi-)automatically. Are you using an Enterprise plan?

Comment: Toolchain is already created,we need to add pipelines and git repos to it and needs to be automated.

Comment: Yes,Using Paid Plan.

Comment: semi automatically?

Comment: Have you tried the options from here? https://github.com/open-toolchain/sdk/wiki/Toolchain-Creation-page-parameters

Comment: Yep,also this post is only for Toolchain creations not adding tools to toolchain